# How to limit facet request to get a certain number of rows

Tags: solr

I have a Solr storage with a huge number of documents. Here's an example of my document structure:

```
{
        "country":"USA",
        "company":"Corsair",
        "product":"RM650X 650W",
        "price":"140",
        "on_stock":"yes"
},
```

I'd like to make a facet request to Solr data to receive a certain number of rows (e.g. 200).

Here's a desired result:

[image]

The problem is I can't limit the data properly.
In Solr [documentation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-Thefacet.limitParameter) it says that "`facet.limit` parameter specifies the maximum number of constraint counts (essentially, the number of facets for a field that are returned) that should be returned for the facet fields. This parameter can be specified on a per-field basis to apply a distinct limit to each field with the syntax of `f.<fieldname>.facet.limit` "

And here comes the tricky part.
I tried to use a limit of 200 for the first column (Country / Region). Here's my request:

```
 country:{
    type: terms,
    field: country,
    limit: 200, # Limit's here
    facet:{
      company:{
        type: terms, 
        field: company,
        limit: -1
        facet:{
          product:{
            type: terms, 
            field: product,
            limit: -1
         }
      }
    }
```

This query returns 200 results for a country facet, but since every country has a different number of nested companies and every company has a different number of nested products, I get thousands of rows of data.

Then I tried to use a limit of 200 for the last column (Product). Here's my request:

```
 country:{
    type: terms,
    field: country,
    limit: -1,
    facet:{
      company:{
        type: terms, 
        field: company,
        limit: -1
        facet:{
          product:{
            type: terms, 
            field: product,
            limit: 200 # Limit's here
         }
      }
    }
```

This query returns 200 results for every product lying withing every company lying within every country. In other words, the limit is local for every nested category, not global. And again I get thousands of rows of data.

Is it possible to achieve my goal in Solr?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the issue, since the facets are generated on what's part of the result set for your query. Having a facet on `country` should give you the count for how many documents have each term; what's unpredictable about this? It should match the number of documents that have the term. If you want to limit it to only fetch 200 rows that match, use `rows=200` together with the query, and if you don't want to show the actual total, display `200` if the value is above `200`.

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for your comment. I've updated my descriprion and included pieces of code for the queries I use.  As for the `rows=200`, how am I supposed to pass this parameter using JSON Facet API?

Comment: It's hard to see what you want to use the result of such a facet for; are you looking for 200 unique `<country>_<company>_<product>` combinations? If that's the case, I think you're going to have to create a field specifically to handle that kind of query; but in that case, I'm guessing that `product` is going to be the dominant factor anyway. If you just want 200 documents, there is no need to do faceting at all, just use `rows=200` for your main query. Usually people want to use facets to narrow down a search result, either by country or company in your case.

Comment: @MatsLindh I'm using facet query to calculate how many times each unique combination of `<country>_<company>_<product>` occurs in my documents. But I need to make this calculation only for the first 200 unique combinations, not for all possible unique combination in my data. I've updated the illustration of the desired result.

Comment: The ideal solution would be to create a new field with the three values separated with a separator (such as `|` or `_`), reindex your content, and then facet across that. The field would then be a single lookup for each unique value. If you can't reindex (which you really, really should be able to do easily), another option might be using a streaming expression, with three `facet` calls with a limit of 200 as the sources, then use stream decorators to create triples for each set of inputs and a final limit to output only 200 tuples.